# Magento get product ordered qty and in stock qty

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I need the simplest way to fetch the quantity of the product ordered and the qty of product in stock. As on product list page there are many products so fetching in stock qty via

```
<?php echo (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty(); ?>
```

is a bit heavy procedure and will result in more load time.

Same for fetching the ordered qty I found below code

```
$sku = nl2br($_product->getSku());
$product = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addOrderedQty()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', $sku)
        ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')
        ->getFirstItem();
echo 'Already Bought ' . (int) $product->ordered_qty;
```

which seemed a bit heavy to me when running in loop for around 1000+ products.

Kindly suggest the best possible solution which will consume least load time and fires less or no queries to DB.

Comment: on which page you want this ?

Comment: as already mentioned above ==> product list page

Comment: there is a magento stack exchange: magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: @DamienBlack http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83998/magento-get-product-ordered-qty-and-in-stock-qty ==>you can answer here if you do not prefer stackoverflow. I have asked on both coz I need the answer, you can compare the timings.